# Java - BufferedImage IOException when clsing window

Tags: java, 2d, bufferedimage, ioexception

I am programming a simple Twin-Stick Shooter at the moment and while I was creating the menu I noticed an IOException in the console when I close the game. It doesn't happen always but most of the time I close the window.

```
java.io.IOException: closed
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.checkClosed(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.close(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at shooter.main.gfx.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:14)
at shooter.main.Menu.render(Menu.java:17)
at shooter.main.Game.render(Game.java:154)
at shooter.main.Game.run(Game.java:200)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am using this class to read in BufferedImages:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    public BufferedImage load(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The line that causes the error:

```
title = game.getImageLoader().load("/gfx/title.png");
```

Personally I am not sure why this happens since I already painted pictures before on the screen and I never got an Exception. Anybody out there who could tell me why this happens? MAybe I have to garbage collect all Buffered Images before closing or something like that?

Comment: Avoid calling garbage collector manually. Also the problem is somewhere else in your code, as thing you showed is fine (well maybe I would have made the method static, but that does not matter). You best bet would be to check those lines again: `at shooter.main.gfx.ImageLoader.load(ImageLoader.java:14)
at shooter.main.Menu.render(Menu.java:17)
at shooter.main.Game.render(Game.java:154)
at shooter.main.Game.run(Game.java:200)`

Comment: I already looked there and there is nothing I see that would cause the problem. The path is correct since the pictures are displayed. The line that causes the error: title = game.getImageLoader().load("/gfx/title.png");

Comment: I'm guessing you are loading the image in your game rendering loop, after the game has closed. Add a listener to your game window to stop the game rendering loop immediately when the window closes.